# Python 3.3 HTTP Cookie Error

Tags: python, http, python-requests, python-3.3

I just did a fresh install (from source) of Python 3.3 and I installed the 'requests' library. I'm attempting a very simple request:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

And I'm getting a very strange error in return:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/http/cookiejar.py", line 1647, in extract_cookies
  if self._policy.set_ok(cookie, request):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/http/cookiejar.py", line 931, in set_ok
  if not fn(cookie, request):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/http/cookiejar.py", line 952, in set_ok_verifiability
  if request.unverifiable and is_third_party(request):
AttributeError: 'MockRequest' object has no attribute 'unverifiable'
```

Seeing as I'm still somewhat a Python beginner, I have absolutely no idea what is causing this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in python 3.2:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 13 2012, 13:31:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

The [`requests` FAQ](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/#python-3-support) states what python 3 versions are officially supported, and you have just found out on python 3.3, `requests` does not (yet) work.

There is a [patch available](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/871) in the issue tracker, so it's only a matter of time.

**Update**: [Version 0.14.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/0.14.1) was released on 2012/10/01, with the fix:

> #### 0.14.1 (2012-10-01)
>
> - Python 3.3 Compatibility
> - Simply default accept-encoding
> - Bugfixes