# Python requests fails to get webpages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Python3 and the package [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to fetch HTML data.

I have tried running the line

`r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')`

, which is the example on their tutorial, to no avail. However, when I run

`request = requests.get('http://www.math.ksu.edu/events/grad_conf_2013/')`

it works fine. I am getting errors such as

```
AttributeError: 'MockRequest' object has no attribute 'unverifiable' 
Error in sys.excepthook:
```

I am thinking the errors have something to do with the type of webpage I am attempting to get, since the html page that is working is just basic html that I wrote.

I am very new to requests and Python in general. I am also new to stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659833/python-3-3-http-cookie-error

Comment: It appears that is outdated

Comment: Anyway, looks like a bug in your specific version of Python, probably related to `https` protocol handling. Works for me with pythons `3.2.3` and `3.3.0`.

Comment: I'm using a fresh install of 3.3, any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Unsure what changed, but after relogging in, thins are working fine...

Comment: Could you add an answer and mark that as the solution. This popped up on my front page again after I removed the tag for 'compiler-errors'

Answer (score 0):

As a little example, here is a little tool which I developed in order to fetch data from a website, in this case IP and show it:

```
# Import the requests module
# TODO: Make sure to install it first
import requests

# Get the raw information from the website
r = requests.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')
raw_page_source_list = r.text
text = ''

# Join the whole list into a single string in order
# to simplify things
text = text.join(raw_page_source_list)

# Get the exact starting position of the IP address string
ip_text_pos = text.find('IP Information') + 62

# Now extract the IP address and store it
ip_address = text[ip_text_pos : ip_text_pos + 12]

# print 'Your IP address is: %s' % ip_address
#           or, for Python 3 ...            #
# print('Your IP address is: %s' % ip_address)
```